# How to perform multiple SQL select queries in batch

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I use Postgis extension for PostgreSQL and have table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE areas
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('areas_id_seq'::regclass),
    name character varying(1024) NOT NULL,
    shape geometry NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_id PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

My application receives several coordinate points (lat/lng pairs) and for each point I need to find corresponding area. So SQL for single point looks like

```
SELECT id, name FROM areas WHERE ST_Within(shape, ST_MakePoint(lng, lat));
```

But I need to perform this query for several points. I can execute separate query for each point, but I guess there shall be a way to achieve it with single query.

Of course I can use UNION here but:

- as far as I understand N queries united with UNION is not faster than separate N queries
- image I have 3 points in input, I combine 3 selects and get only 2 areas in result. I need to understand which area which point corresponds to (and which point has no associated area), and it means I need to do it in my code (which could be long if there are 3000 points instead of 3) even the PostGIS already made all checks.

I think can create temporary table, put input points there and then perform JOIN select for both tables. But probably there is a better way.

So question is: what is the faster way in PostgreSQL (or any other RDBMS) for N input values execute same query and get exact N results in same order as input values (assuming that for some input values result will be NULL)?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could try something like this:

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, p.which
FROM areas a JOIN
     (SELECT lng1 as lng, lat1 as lat, 'point1' as which UNION ALL
      SELECT lng2, lat2, 'point2' as which
     ) p
     ON ST_Within(a.shape, ST_MakePoint(p.lng, p.lat));
```